# UISearchController incorrect behavior when it is present modally

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uisearchcontroller

I showed `UIViewController` like modal style. `UIViewController` has `UITableView`. I added `UISearchController` to `UITableView` but `UISearchController` has incorrect behavior when it disappeared. I made many times `UISearchControllers` but I didn't face the this behavior.

My code

So I show the `UIViewController`

```
 @objc fileprivate func selectInterlocutor(_ button: UIButton) {
        let selectInterlocutorTVC = SelectInterlocutorTableViewController()
        selectInterlocutorTVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        selectInterlocutorTVC.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
        selectInterlocutorTVC.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
        present(selectInterlocutorTVC, animated: true) {

        }
    }
```

I add `UISearchController` to `tableView`

```
  fileprivate func addSearchController() {
        searchController.searchBar.barStyle = .default
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .words
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }
```

Please look at this video that you can see this behavior.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/l3m3q8wmqoy3qv2/SearchBarBug.mov?dl=0

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `UISearchController` and I used `UISearchBar` and it works for me.

```
 fileprivate func addSearchController() {
        searchBar.barStyle = .default
        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .words
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        searchBar.sizeToFit()

        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
    }
```